# preg_match_all does not match data in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm actually trying to pull out all the text on lines that begins with `*`, `**` and `***` alone, and not any other text that's under or above it. Only text on lines beginning with `*`,`**`,`***`.

That data comes from a textarea in a form and looks like this:

```
*Heading 1*
User Text
**SubHeading 1A**
More UserText
***SubSubHeading 1AA***
More UserText
**SubHeading 1B**
More UserText
**Subheading 1C**
More UserText
**Subheading 1D**
More UserText
*Heading 2*
More UserText
**SubHeading 2A**
More UserText
**SubHeading 2B**
More UserText
**Subheading 2C**
More UserText
***Subheading 2C**
More UserText
```

The end result is to only end up with results like this, and not any of the user text.

```
Heading 1
SubHeading 1A
SubSubHeading 1AA
SubHeading 1B
Subheading 1C
Subheading 1D
Heading 2
SubHeading 2A
SubHeading 2B
Subheading 2C
Subheading 2D
```

I modified a previous answer to match only lines beginning with `*`, `**` and `***`, but i don't seem to be getting any results, just a blank array.

```
if (preg_match_all('/^\*{1},{2},{3}([^\*].*)$/', $text, $matches))
        $result = array_map(function ($v) {
                return str_replace('*', ' ', rtrim($v, '*'));
        }, $matches[1]);

print_r($result);
```

How could I do this to get results I want? I cant figure where I'm failing.

Comment: one problem is that `\*{1},{2},{3}` should be `\*{1,3}`

Comment: Changed that, but still the same. Matter of fact, your suggestion is the way I had it before.

Comment: /^(\*{1,3})(.+?)\1$/m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can se this regex:

```
$s = <<< EOF
*Heading 1*
User Text
**SubHeading 1A**
More UserText
***SubSubHeading 1AA***
More UserText
**SubHeading 1B**
More UserText
**Subheading 1C**
More UserText
**Subheading 1D**
More UserText
*Heading 2*
More UserText
**SubHeading 2A**
More UserText
**SubHeading 2B**
More UserText
**Subheading 2C**
More UserText
***Subheading 2D**
More UserText
EOF;
if ( preg_match_all('~^\*{1,3}(.+?)\*{1,3}$~m', $s, $m) )
   print_r($m[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Heading 1
    [1] => SubHeading 1A
    [2] => SubSubHeading 1AA
    [3] => SubHeading 1B
    [4] => Subheading 1C
    [5] => Subheading 1D
    [6] => Heading 2
    [7] => SubHeading 2A
    [8] => SubHeading 2B
    [9] => Subheading 2C
    [10] => Subheading 2D
)
```

Comment: Are you sure you used `m` flag.

Comment: I'm on PHP 5.3.13. Could have something to do with this? I've simply copied and pasted your code and It's just blank :-)

Comment: Did you check ideone demo I provided? It should work on PHP 5.3.13 also.

Comment: Can you try: `preg_match_all('~\*{1,3}(.+?)\*{1,3}~', $s, $m)` ?

Comment: Ok. I got it going. Must have been the EOF thing.

Comment: Glad to know it is working for you. You may accept the answer now, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\*+(.*?)\*+
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/tR5hC6/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1-10]  `Heading 1`
MATCH 2
1.  [24-37] `SubHeading 1A`
MATCH 3
1.  [57-74] `SubSubHeading 1AA`
MATCH 4
1.  [94-107]    `SubHeading 1B`
MATCH 5
1.  [126-139]   `Subheading 1C`
MATCH 6
1.  [158-171]   `Subheading 1D`
MATCH 7
1.  [189-198]   `Heading 2`
MATCH 8
1.  [216-229]   `SubHeading 2A`
MATCH 9
1.  [248-261]   `SubHeading 2B`
MATCH 10
1.  [280-293]   `Subheading 2C`
MATCH 11
1.  [313-326]   `Subheading 2C`
```

Comment: Use this regex in my code, or there's a different way?

Comment: @jmenezes sorry didn't understand your question

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a change of the PCRE to `'/(*ANYCRLF)^(\*{1,3})([^\*]+?)\1$/m'` to eliminate the last invalid row (thanks to `'[^\*]'`) and to **ensure not empty** array of results on various OS-es (thanks to `'(*ANYCRLF)'` official PCRE option modifier - undocumented on [php.net](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) at the moment) with different end line (a.k.a line break) chars (`"\r\n"`, `"\n"` or even just `"\r"`) like this:

```
<?php 
$str=<<<'STR'
*Heading 1*
User Text
**SubHeading 1A**
More UserText
***SubSubHeading 1AA***
More UserText
**SubHeading 1B**
More UserText
**Subheading 1C**
More UserText
**Subheading 1D**
More UserText
*Heading 2*
More UserText
**SubHeading 2A**
More UserText
**SubHeading 2B**
More UserText
**Subheading 2C**
More UserText
***Subheading 2C**
More UserText

STR;
$pat='/(*ANYCRLF)^(\*{1,3})(.+?)\1$/m';
$n=preg_match_all($pat, $str, $m);
// Your result is in $m[2] but take a look at the entire $m
echo ">>>\t\t1:\n$str\n($n) ".print_r($m, true)."\nResult WITH last invalid(?) row:\n".print_r($m[2], true);
// Last row contains invalid(?) number of stars (3 on the left and 2 on the right side)

$pat='/(*ANYCRLF)^(\*{1,3})([^\*]+?)\1$/m';
$n=preg_match_all($pat, $str, $m);
echo "\n>>>\t\t2:\n$str\n($n) ".print_r($m, true)."\nResult WITHOUT last invalid(?) row:\n".print_r($m[2], true);
// The last invalid row was eliminated
?>
```

It all depends on where your data comes from - external and uncontrolled sources might provide quite messy data.
A hint for those of you who are trying to fight off (or work around at least) the problem of matching a pattern correctly at the end ($) of any line in multiple lines mode (/m).

```
<?php 
// Various OS-es have various end line (a.k.a line break) chars:
// - Windows uses CR+LF (\r\n);
// - Linux LF (\n);
// - OSX CR (\r).
// And that's why single dollar meta assertion ($) sometimes fails with multiline modifier (/m) mode - possible bug in PHP 5.3.8 or just a "feature"(?).
$str="ABC ABC\n\n123 123\r\ndef def\rnop nop\r\n890 890\nQRS QRS\r\r~-_ ~-_";
//          C          3                   p          0                   _
$pat1='/\w$/mi';    // This works excellent in JavaScript (Firefox 7.0.1+)
$pat2='/\w\r?$/mi'; // Slightly better
$pat3='/\w\R?$/mi'; // Somehow disappointing according to php.net and pcre.org when used improperly
$pat4='/\w(?=\R)/i';    // Much better with allowed lookahead assertion (just to detect without capture) without multiline (/m) mode; note that with alternative for end of string ((?=\R|$)) it would grab all 7 elements as expected
$pat5='/\w\v?$/mi';
$pat6='/(*ANYCRLF)\w$/mi';  // Excellent but undocumented on php.net at the moment (described on pcre.org and en.wikipedia.org)
$n=preg_match_all($pat1, $str, $m1);
$o=preg_match_all($pat2, $str, $m2);
$p=preg_match_all($pat3, $str, $m3);
$r=preg_match_all($pat4, $str, $m4);
$s=preg_match_all($pat5, $str, $m5);
$t=preg_match_all($pat6, $str, $m6);
echo $str."\n1 !!! $pat1 ($n): ".print_r($m1[0], true)
    ."\n2 !!! $pat2 ($o): ".print_r($m2[0], true)
    ."\n3 !!! $pat3 ($p): ".print_r($m3[0], true)
    ."\n4 !!! $pat4 ($r): ".print_r($m4[0], true)
    ."\n5 !!! $pat5 ($s): ".print_r($m5[0], true)
    ."\n6 !!! $pat6 ($t): ".print_r($m6[0], true);
// Note the difference among the three very helpful escape sequences in $pat2 (\r), $pat3 and $pat4 (\R), $pat5 (\v) and altered newline option in $pat6 ((*ANYCRLF)) - for some applications at least.

/* The code above results in the following output:
ABC ABC

123 123
def def
nop nop
890 890
QRS QRS

~-_ ~-_
1 !!! /\w$/mi (3): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 0
    [2] => _
)

2 !!! /\w\r?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

3 !!! /\w\R?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C

    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

4 !!! /\w(?=\R)/i (6): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => f
    [3] => p
    [4] => 0
    [5] => S
)

5 !!! /\w\v?$/mi (5): Array
(
    [0] => C

    [1] => 3
    [2] => p
    [3] => 0
    [4] => _
)

6 !!! /(*ANYCRLF)\w$/mi (7): Array
(
    [0] => C
    [1] => 3
    [2] => f
    [3] => p
    [4] => 0
    [5] => S
    [6] => _
)
 */
?>
```

Unfortunately, I haven't got any access to a server with the latest PHP version - my local PHP is 5.3.8 and my public host's PHP is version 5.2.17.